# How to merge a loose edge into coplanar faces?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I created this edge by linking the two vertices directly (`Make Edge / Face`):

[image]

Now I would like to split the quad face below along this loose edge. What is the solution for the general case where the edge crosses multiple coplanar faces?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no way to use an edge (without even a plane) to divide a face.

What you need to do is delete the edge (x->edge) and then join the two verts, by selecting them and hitting 'j'.

If you've made a bunch of edges not realizing what you were doing in some other model, you can use mesh->cleanup->delete loose to delete all these edges, but I don't believe there's any way to transform them into cuts.

Comment: Actually you don't have to delete the edge first. With the loose edge selected `J` will still cut the underlying face, turning the loose edge into an edge between faces. You can use `Select Loose Geometry` to find the edges you want to fix.

Comment: @sambler You don't have to delete the edge first, but you do have to delete the edge.

Comment: Right you are, easy to miss two edges in the same position.